# return array with toString()

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

I have an array and I would like to return it in the end but I dont know how to return it with the name and the `[]`. All I get now is `s[[LCat;@3b250bf7]`

This is my arrray and a class of cats. I start at 0 because I only want to make the array bigger if i have to.

```
private Cat[] ownedCats = new Cat[0];
```

This is my code i use to return the array now but i dont know how to make it work.

```
public String toString() {
    return name +"[" + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What appears from your question is that you are trying to get a formatted string representation of your cat array.

First you should have `toString()` method defined for your cat class.

Then use `Arrays.toString()` method to get the string representation of your cats array.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to override `toString()` method in Cat class:

```java
public class Cat {
    //...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // return string that represents your object (like name)
    }
}
```

Then use:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ownedCats));
```